# Is the rank of a Tensor different from the rank of a Matrix?

Tags: matrices, tensors, tensor-rank

As far as I know, the rank of a matrix is the dimension of the vector space generated by columns.

In NumPy notation, 
`x = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4]])` has a rank of one.

`np.linalg.matrix_rank(x)` confirms that it is one.

While studying the TensorFlow page shown below, https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started
I saw the following remarks:

```
A tensor's rank is its number of dimensions. Here are some examples of tensors:

3 # a rank 0 tensor; this is a scalar with shape []
[1. ,2., 3.] # a rank 1 tensor; this is a vector with shape [3]
[[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]] # a rank 2 tensor; a matrix with shape [2, 3]
[[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]] # a rank 3 tensor with shape [2, 1, 3]
```

I'm totally confused.

Q1. What is the relationship between the rank of a Matrix and the rank of a Tensor? Is it a completely different thing?

Q2. In the case of the above matrix `x = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4]])`, is the rank two if we assume that it is a tensor not a matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Often in math the same word is used to mean totally different things.  Don't let bad naming confuse you.

Comment: Briefly, any matrix is a tensor of rank 2. In general, a tensor is going to "eat" a certain number of vectors and output a real number; the number of vectors it eats is the rank of the tensor. (More generally, it can eat a certain number of vectors and spit out another number of vectors. The rank will be the sum of those numbers.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Does that assume the tensor is (at least) partially covariant?

Comment: @Chill2Macht: Well, I was being slightly sloppy. Of course, I should have stated that it "eats" a certain number of vectors and a number of covectors. I was trying to be as concrete as possible.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes sense. I just wanted to test my understanding of the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"number of dimensions" is a pretty terrible description. Looking at the website, their interpretation of "tensor" is not the same as the strict mathematical definition (which is to do with multilinear maps with certain properties).

As far as that program is concerned, a tensor is a vector of vectors of vectors of... of vectors, where the *rank* is the number of nestings of "of vectors", so

- A tensor of rank $1$ is a vector, which is a one-dimensional array, `[a,b]`.
- A tensor of rank $2$ is a vector of vectors, or a matrix, or a two-dimensional array, `[[a,b],[c,d]]`.
- A tensor of rank $3$ is a vector of vectors of vectors, so something with three nestings, `[[[a,b],[c,d]],[[e,f],[g,h]]]` sort of thing.
- &c.

The "dimension" here is the (tensorial) rank, or the number of inputs you need to locate an entry. This is of course not the same as "dimension" in the sense that something has "dimension $n$" if is an ordered list of length $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The rank you mentioned are defined differently in the two kinds of context you mentioned.

In tensorflow, the (tenorial) **rank** is simply the number of indices to speficy an entry. Eg. `a = np.array([[[a,b],[c,d]],[[e,f],[g,h]]])`, the tensor rank is 3. This is also the same as `len(a.shape)`. Furthermore, you can always flatten this tensor, which will reduce its rank.
On the other hand, in `a.shape = (1, 1, 2)`, the entries in a.shape tuple are vector **dimensions** for each index, ie the range of each index.

In linear algebra, the vector rank is the number of linear independent vectors (ie noncoplanary from geometric point of view). This vector rank decides the dimension of the spanned space. Note that here the dimension is the mathematical dimension which measures the linear independency, not the dimension above which is the simple counting.

Furthermore, in linear algebra, the basis of vector space can be matrix rows, matrix columns, even matrix entries, or any F-modules. The number of the basis is vector dimension.